# Shiny dashboard to display data based on two conditional variable choices

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I've been on this all night so I hope someone could help me. I am not proficient in Rshiny at all.

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)
full_data <- tibble::tribble(
~Key, ~Description, ~DetailsAvailable, ~Inputs, ~Choices, ~Unit,
"AAAA", "descrAAAA", NA, "input1", NA, "miles",
"AAAA", "descrAAAA", NA, "input2", NA, "date",
"AAAA", "descrAAAA", NA, "input3", NA, "USD",
"BBBB", "descrBBBB", "yes", "input1", NA, "miles",
"BBBB", "descrBBBB", "yes", "input4", NA, "USD",  
"BBBB", "descrBBBB", "no", "selectinput1", "input1", "miles",
"BBBB", "descrBBBB", "no", "selectinput1", "input2", "date",
"BBBB", "descrBBBB", "no", "selectinput2", "input5", "USD",
"BBBB", "descrBBBB", "no", "selectinput2", "input3", "USD",
"BBBB", "descrBBBB", "no", "input7", NA, "USD",
"BBBB", "descrBBBB", "no", "input8", NA, "miles"
)
```

What I want:

Select unique entries of `Key` (AAAA and BBBB) from a dropdown. Conditional on key, the variable `DetailsAvailable` (yes, no) can be selected from a second drop down. Then, I want to see unique entries (as in, I don't want the description of AAAA, which is the same for all AAAA entries, to be displayed multiple times).

- Example output 1

I select `AAAA` from the drop down. Since DetailsAvailable is N/A, there will be no second drop down menu.

Output:

**Key**: AAAA

**Description**: descrAAAA

**DetailsAvailable**: N/A

| Inputs | Unit |
| --- | --- |
| input1 | miles |
| input2 | date |
| input3 | USD |

- Example output 2

I select `BBBB` from the drop down. A second drop down appears and I select "no".

Output:

**Key**: BBBB

**Description**: descrBBBB

**DetailsAvailable**: no

| Inputs | InputChoice | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| selectinput1 | input1 | miles |
| selectinput1 | input2 | date |
| selectinput2 | input3 | USD |
| selectinput2 | input5 | USD |
| input7 |  | USD |
| input8 |  | miles |

Comment: Show us what you have tried.